# fromJson GSON Complex Class

Tags: json, class, object, gson

I have the following code.

```
public class SomeClass {


    private List<SomeOtherClass> referrals;

    public  List<SomeOtherClass> getReferrals() {
        return referrals;
    }

    public void setReferrals( List<SomeOtherClass> referrals) {
        this.referrals = referrals;
    }

}
```

I have a json that I read from the wire. It is correctly formatted. I use GSON

My question is :

when I do fromJson(jsonString,SomeClass.class); 
it gives an exception.

If I don't use  `List<SomeOtherClass>` but instead use `List<String>` for referrals.
(in other word a primitive)

And iterate over each String and create SomeOtherClass object it works fine.

Why can't I just use fromJson(jsonString,SomeClass.class);

Comment: Please add the code of `SomeOtherClass` and a sample of the JSON you're trying to parse to your question. Something between those two doesn't match up.

Comment: Also, the exact exception with message and stacktrace would help.